# Fusion Tables won't sync with Google Sheet: "FusionTables" not defined

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-forms

Trying to get data into Fusion Table using Google sheets and forms.

Using script provided here:
http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesFormSync/src/formsync.js

Have enabled Fusion Tables for both Apps Script and Developer Console.

Data from form appears on sheet, along with new 'rowid' column, but does not appear in Fusion Table.

Here is the execution log:

> [15-01-27 10:58:32:639 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0
>   seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:32:639 PST] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 10:58:32:639 PST] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds] [15-01-27
>   10:58:32:639 PST] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:32:639
>   PST] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:32:640 PST]
>   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds] [15-01-27
>   10:58:32:713 PST] Starting execution [15-01-27 10:58:32:718 PST]
>   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:32:929
>   PST] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.21 seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:32:943 PST]
>   UserProperties.getProperty([docid]) [0.012 seconds] [15-01-27
>   10:58:32:956 PST] ScriptProperties.getProperty([docid]) [0.012
>   seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:32:973 PST]
>   UserProperties.getProperty([addressColumn]) [0.015 seconds] [15-01-27
>   10:58:32:986 PST] ScriptProperties.getProperty([addressColumn]) [0.012
>   seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:33:010 PST]
>   UserProperties.getProperty([latlngColumn]) [0.021 seconds] [15-01-27
>   10:58:33:026 PST] ScriptProperties.getProperty([latlngColumn]) [0.014
>   seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:33:026 PST] Session.getScriptTimeZone() [0
>   seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:33:026 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
>   [0 seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:33:183 PST] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.156
>   seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:33:183 PST] Sheet.getRange([1, 4]) [0
>   seconds] [15-01-27 10:58:33:374 PST] Range.getValue() [0.19 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 10:58:33:375 PST] Utilities.formatDate([Tue Jan 27 10:58:31
>   PST 2015, America/Los_Angeles, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]) [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 10:58:33:381 PST] Execution failed: Problem running SQL:
>   INSERT INTO 1oKqThZc0lxw5w_Z2EQ7aYobysWKJKbTYWFolZfoM
>   ('Location','Dust Density','Timestamp') VALUES ('Test -
>   Encinitas','Test - 120','1/27/2015 10:58:31'): ReferenceError:
>   "FusionTables" is not defined.. (line 308, file "Code") [0.662 seconds
>   total runtime]

Help! Please!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I had enabled Fusion Tables yesterday, and when I checked today, they were no longer enabled. Don't know why that is, but that was the problem.